# Minimize method injection parameters in SpringBoot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm relatively new to the Spring community and I have a question about reducing the number of method injection parameters.

Example

**Config Class**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    @Bean
    public Step readStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step validateStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step writeStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

}
```

**Job Class**

```
public class SomeJob {

    @Bean
    public Job someServiceMethod(@Qualifier("readStep" Step readStep, 
           @Qualifier("writeStep" Step writeStep,
           @Qualifier("validateStep" Step validateStep) {
              //Do something
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the number of method injection parameters to one. Example maybe injecting CustomConfig.java as a parameter vs each individual bean.

```
public class SomeJob {

    @Bean
    public Job someServiceMethod(CustomConfig config) {
        config.readStep//etc
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: From my point of view with Spring we can split project to small beans with one responsibility but you are trying to do something oposit. Strange why are you want to do it?

Comment: @Alexey Usharovsk I'm using spring batch where I have many jobs with a config class that has some shared beans across jobs. When I create my Job bean, I need to get those shared beans to my job configuration. The actual shared beans are Step's.

Comment: cleaned up my question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create @component with all required bean already injected.
Name it like MyCustomJobCommonCOnfig and use it as one method parameter.

Comment: This seems close to what I'm looking for, could you provide a little sample code to demo this option?

Comment: Would I continue to use my CustomConfig with the Configuration annotation and create an additional class MyCustomjob with the Component annotation and just inject all my required beans into the component? Or can this be done in the configuration class using the Component annotation instead of the configuration annotation?

Comment: I mean you can create just one more bean/comoponent and inject there all bean that you want.
You can create it as separate class in separate file or like one more method annothated bean with sub class in same file. It's no matter, do it as you feel convinient.

Comment: I keep forgetting about the bean concept in Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a code example for Grigoriev Nick answer.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    //Create a component injecting required beans into it. 
    @Getter
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class JobConfig {
        private final Step readStep;
        private final Step validateStep;
        private final Step writeStep;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step readStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step validateStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step writeStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }

}

public class SomeJob {

    //Inject comonent into method. 
    @Bean
    public Job someServiceMethod(JobConfig config) {
          Step read = config.getReadStep(),
               validate = config.getValidateStep(),
               write = config.getWriteStep();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Add a name for each bean in the `CustomConfig`:

```
@Bean(name="readStep")
    public Step readStep() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
```

Then simply instantiate a `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and use the `register` method which accepts a bean configuration class then use the `getBean` method to get individual beans.

```
public class SomeJob {

  @Bean
  public Job someServiceMethod() {
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

  applicaionContext.register(CustomConfig.class);
  applicationContext.refresh();

  Step readStep = (Step) applicationContext.getBean("readStep");

  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be more complex than what I'm already doing. Grigoriev Nick seems to think I could just use @Component and inject the component, so I'm hoping to see a little sample as for how to do that, but might be much simpler.

Comment: Just wanted to comment about the code that you've added as an answer, and i commented here because i cannot comment on other answers yet. You are instantiating the beans as objects, not spring beans, so you need to use @Autowired for each object in the JobConfig before you inject it, also make a separate class (not an inner class) for these beans just as Grigoriev Nick mentioned.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken RequiredArgsConstructor is handling the autowire automatically for me. I was under the understanding that lombok is using Constructor injection. The code appeared to be working in test without any issues. Would this still work if the autowire was not there?

Comment: I see. I didn't know about the RequiredArgsConstructor, it handles constructor wiring.

Comment: Yes, I like how it cleans up the code. With the exception of removing the inner class, do you have any other suggestions?